# Como recuperar o html apresentada em uma UIWebView com swift para IOS

Tags: ios, swift

Quando meu aplicativo inicia o método **viewDidLoad** executa um trecho de código que acessa um site X, recupera um formulário HTML e o apresenta em uma UIWebView.

Meu problema é o seguinte, quando um link for clicado necessito interceptar o HTML de retorno para efetuar outro tratamento, porém, não sei como detectar que a webview foi atualizada com uma nova requisição nem tão pouco como pegar o html ali presente.

Answer (score 0):

no HTML...

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="myId" type="hidden" value="TextValue"/>
</body>
</html>
```

no Swift...

```
var id:String = IBwebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('myId').value")!
println(id)
```

no Obj c:

```
NSString* value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('myId').value"];
```

Comment: preciso capturar todo o html de retorno, ou seja, quero capturar todo o código de retorno.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve implementar o protocolo [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/), e realizar a ação que você precisa no método *viewDidFinishLoad*.